# Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesArray@0

Tags: elasticsearch

My curl query works

`curl -v -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/entityitem/5/_mget' -d '{"ids" : ["5000027585", "5000027615"]}'`

but when I use the rest client to do GET query

`http://localhost:9200/entityitem/5/_mget?source={"ids" : ["5000027585", "5000027615"]}`

I get the following error

> Failed to derive xcontent from org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesArray@0

Comment: In my case, I got this error when query's body was empty.

Answer (score 9):

If you get this while following the kibana tutorial you may be trying to import the shakespeare.json file.  You probably downloaded to downloads folder and are running the import command in another folder. Move the input file to the current directory...

```
mv ~/Downloads/shakespeare.json .
```

and run your curl xput command to import the shakespeare data.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @shakespeare.json
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. It's an issue.

I just fixed it yesterday. See https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4892

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
http://localhost:9200/entityitem/5/_mget?q=ids:5000027585%20OR%20ids:5000027615
```

q is query. ids is your field. The URL above is equal to query

> ids:5000027585 OR ids:5000027615

That's the lucene syntax supported by Elasticsearch. Remember to use %20 to replace space.